# I can't get the correct CHECKED value on my bootstrap table

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having a problem on retrieving the `checked` value of my checked row. The following is my code snippet of columns inside my bootstrap table.

```
//TABLE [REG CURRENCY CODE]

var allRegCurrencyCode = {};

function loadRegCurrencyCode() {
    allRegCurrencyCode = {
        method: 'get',
        url: "",
        cache: false,
        striped: true,
        pagination: true,
        showColumns: true,
        showRefresh: true,
        pageSize: 25,
        pageList: [10, 25, 50, 100, 200],
        search: true,
        minimumCountColumns: 2,
        columns: [{
            field: 'checkbox',
            class: 'RegCurrencyCode_checkBox',
            checkbox: true,
            align: 'center'
        }, {
            field: 'currency_code',
            title: 'CURRENCY CODE',
            align: 'center',
            sortable: true,
            visible: true,
        }, {
            field: 'currency_desc',
            title: 'CURRENCY DESCRIPTION',
            align: 'center',
            sortable: true,
            visible: true,
        }, {
            field: 'currency_loc',
            title: 'CURRENCY LOC',
            align: 'center',
            sortable: true,
            visible: true,
        }, {
            field: 'created_date',
            title: 'CREATED DATE',
            align: 'center',
            sortable: true,
            visible: true,
        }, {
            field: 'created_by',
            title: 'CREATED BY',
            align: 'center',
            sortable: true,
        }, {
            field: 'last_modified_date',
            title: 'LAST MODIFIED DATE',
            align: 'center',
            sortable: true,
        }, {
            field: 'last_modified_by',
            title: 'LAST MODIFIED BY',
            align: 'center',
            sortable: true,
        }, {
            field: 'tax_status_flag',
            title: 'TAX STATUS FLAG',
            align: 'center',
            sortable: true,
        }, ]
    }
    var regCurrencyCode = Liferay.PortletURL.createResourceURL();
    regCurrencyCode.setPortletId(
        "codestablemaintenance_WAR_triumainportlet");
    regCurrencyCode.setResourceId('getRegCurrencyCode');
    allRegCurrencyCode.url = regCurrencyCode.toString();
    console.log("---->> " + regCurrencyCode.toString());
    $('#codes-table-maintenance').bootstrapTable('destroy');
    $('#codes-table-maintenance').bootstrapTable(allRegCurrencyCode);
}
```

Then here is my function on retrieving the `checked` values:

```
 var allData = $('#codes-table-maintenance').bootstrapTable('getData');
 $.each(allData, function(i, rowData) {
     if (rowData.checkbox == true) {
         console.log(i)
     }
 });
```

Now, my problem is when I'm running my function, I can't get the correct **checked** values. If i checked one row, sometimes it says true sometimes false and sometimes undefined. What is the proper way to retrieve the selected row if checked? is it possible to use with my existing code? Thanks.

Comment: Try this if it will work for you `$(".RegCurrencyCode_checkBox").live('click', function (e) {
var tr = $(e.target).closest('tr').attr('id');
});` or this `var check= $(e.target).is(':checked');`

Comment: are you trying to get the check status by click event?